# Find Function in Loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find

I have the following VBA code. I want to make a calculation, but this can only be done if the IF statements are met. This means that the dates in 5 different sheets should be the same in a certain cell and that client names should be equal in another. The dates and names are displayed in different ways along the sheets.
If I would use the first code, then the code works. BUT the first two rows used in the if statement code, finds not the correct value, because the fomrat/display of these are not the same in the different sheets that are used.
So I think it is necessairy to use the find function, to find the correct value needed for the calculation. The code using the find function is shown in the second macro provided.When I try to run this code, I get an Error 91. So assume something is wrong with the find functions I made, but I can not find the mistake I made. 
Does somebody know what is going wrong in the second code?

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoSomething1()


    'Declare Variables
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim count as Double, lastColData as Double, LastRowData as Double, lastRowInput as Double, StartSearch2 As Double
    Dim shtData As Worksheet, shtInput As Worksheet, shtInputI As Worksheet, shtInputII As Worksheet, shtInputIII As Worksheet, shtInputIV As Worksheet, shtInputV As Worksheet, shtInputVI As Worksheet, shtCopy As Worksheet
    Set shtData = Sheets("Data")
    Set shtInput = Sheets("INPUT")
    Set shtInputI = Sheets("INPUTP")
    Set shtInputII = Sheets("INPUTR")
    Set shtInputIII = Sheets("INPUTF")
    Set shtInputIV = Sheets("INPUTQ")
    Set shtInputV = Sheets("INPUTPF")
    LastColData = shtData.Cells(4, shtData.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRowData = shtData.Cells(shtData.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    LastRowInput = shtInput.Cells(shtInput.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row


    'Search starting from which row?
    StartSearch2 = InputBox("Vanaf welke rij wil je zoeken?", "Start", Default:=6)


    'Loop Code
    For r = StartSearch2 To LastRowData
        For c = 2 To LastColData
            count = 0
            For i = 2 To LastRowInput


                If shtInput.Cells(i,10).Value = shtData.Cells(r,1).Value And _
            shtInputI.Cells(r, 1).Value = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value And _
                    shtInputIV.Cells(r, 1).Value = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value And _
                    shtInputIII.Cells(r, 1).Value = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value And _
                    shtInputII.Cells(r, 1).Value = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value Then   'Dates are equal in different sheets

                            If shtInput.Cells(i,32).Value = shtData.Cells(4,c).Value And _
                shtInputI.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                                shtInputV.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                                shtInputIV.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                                shtInputIII.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                                shtInputII.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value Then   'Names are equal in different sheets


                            count = count + (shtInputI.Cells(r, c).Value + shtInputII.Cells(r, c)) * shtInputV.Cells(5, c).Value * shtInputIV.Cells(r, c).Value * shtInputIII.Cells(r, c).Value

                            End If
                End If



            Next i

            shtData.Cells(r, c).Value = count
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoSomething2()


    'Declare Variables
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim count as Double, lastColData as Double, LastRowData as Double, lastRowInput as Double, StartSearch2 As Double
    Dim shtData As Worksheet, shtInput As Worksheet, shtInputI As Worksheet, shtInputII As Worksheet, shtInputIII As Worksheet, shtInputIV As Worksheet, shtInputV As Worksheet, shtInputVI As Worksheet, shtCopy As Worksheet
    Set shtData = Sheets("Data")
    Set shtInput = Sheets("INPUT")
    Set shtInputI = Sheets("INPUTP")
    Set shtInputII = Sheets("INPUTR")
    Set shtInputIII = Sheets("INPUTF")
    Set shtInputIV = Sheets("INPUTQ")
    Set shtInputV = Sheets("INPUTPF")
    LastColData = shtData.Cells(4, shtData.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRowData = shtData.Cells(shtData.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    LastRowInput = shtInput.Cells(shtInput.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row


    'Search starting from which row?
    StartSearch2 = InputBox("Vanaf welke rij wil je zoeken?", "Start", Default:=6)


    'Loop Code
    For r = StartSearch2 To LastRowData
        For c = 2 To LastColData
            count = 0
            For i = 2 To LastRowInput



        If shtInput.Cells.Find(What:=shtInput.Cells(i, 10).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext) = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value And _
            shtInputI.Cells.Find(What:=shtInputI.Cells(r, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext) = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value And _
                    shtInputIV.Cells(r, 1).Value = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value And _
                    shtInputIII.Cells(r, 1).Value = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value And _
                    shtInputII.Cells(r, 1).Value = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value Then

                            If shtInput.Cells.Find(What:=shtInput.Cells(i, 32).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext) = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                            shtInputI.Cells.Find(What:=shtInputI.Cells(4, c).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext) = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And ?
                                shtInputV.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                                shtInputIV.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                                shtInputIII.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                                shtInputII.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value Then

                            count = count + (shtInputI.Cells(r, c).Value + shtInputII.Cells(r, c)) * shtInputV.Cells(5, c).Value * shtInputIV.Cells(r, c).Value * shtInputIII.Cells(r, c).Value

                            End If
                End If



            Next i

            shtData.Cells(r, c).Value = count
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Won't the find function just return `shtInput.Cells(i, 10).Value`?

Comment: The error is probably because it is not finding the search term.

Answer (score 0):

To start, there is at least 1 typo: `shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And` **?** instead of **_**

Then, if it was me, i would put this find in a variable, then evaluate the variable instead... makes it easier to trace any issues, especially when the value is not found.

```
Sub DoSomething2()


    'Declare Variables
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim count As Double, lastColData As Double, LastRowData As Double, lastRowInput As Double, StartSearch2 As Double
    Dim shtData As Worksheet, shtInput As Worksheet, shtInputI As Worksheet, shtInputII As Worksheet, shtInputIII As Worksheet, shtInputIV As Worksheet, shtInputV As Worksheet, shtInputVI As Worksheet, shtCopy As Worksheet
    Set shtData = Sheets("Data")
    Set shtInput = Sheets("INPUT")
    Set shtInputI = Sheets("INPUTP")
    Set shtInputII = Sheets("INPUTR")
    Set shtInputIII = Sheets("INPUTF")
    Set shtInputIV = Sheets("INPUTQ")
    Set shtInputV = Sheets("INPUTPF")
    lastColData = shtData.Cells(4, shtData.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRowData = shtData.Cells(shtData.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowInput = shtInput.Cells(shtInput.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    'Search starting from which row?
    StartSearch2 = InputBox("Vanaf welke rij wil je zoeken?", "Start", Default:=6)


    'Loop Code
    For r = StartSearch2 To LastRowData
        For c = 2 To lastColData
            count = 0
            For i = 2 To lastRowInput



        If shtInput.Cells.Find(What:=shtInput.Cells(i, 10).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext) = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value And _
            shtInputI.Cells.Find(What:=shtInputI.Cells(r, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext) = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value And _
                    shtInputIV.Cells(r, 1).Value = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value And _
                    shtInputIII.Cells(r, 1).Value = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value And _
                    shtInputII.Cells(r, 1).Value = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value Then

                            If shtInput.Cells.Find(What:=shtInput.Cells(i, 32).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext) = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                            shtInputI.Cells.Find(What:=shtInputI.Cells(4, c).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext) = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                                shtInputV.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                                shtInputIV.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                                shtInputIII.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value And _
                                shtInputII.Cells(4, c).Value = shtData.Cells(4, c).Value Then

                            count = count + (shtInputI.Cells(r, c).Value + shtInputII.Cells(r, c)) * shtInputV.Cells(5, c).Value * shtInputIV.Cells(r, c).Value * shtInputIII.Cells(r, c).Value

                            End If
                End If



            Next i

            shtData.Cells(r, c).Value = count
        Next c
    Next r
```